# How to return the table with javascript or jquery by returning another table with all the rows that contains a td that doesn't have a colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to return the table with javascript or jquery by returning another table with all the rows that contains a td that doesn't have a colspan

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> text1 </td>
    <td> text2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> text3 </td>
    <td> text4 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thus I'm expecting

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> text1 </td>
    <td> text2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> text3 </td>
    <td> text4 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single line of jQuery for this with the `:has` selector:

```
$('table tr:has(td[colspan])').remove();
```

Comment: Ok so I can remove the td's and then get the table afterwards that doesn't contain the td's. Is there a way to retrieve the table without removing any elements from it?  If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, just `$('table')` will do that

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase, the call you provided will affect the table by removing the specific td's. I don't want the table to be affected/modified by my actions. I want to retrieve the table with rows that has no td that contains a colspan without affecting the given table

Comment: `$('table').clone().find('tr:has(td[colspan])').remove();` maybe

Comment: You can't really do that. the `td` elements are all children of the `table`. You can't take a parent without all of its children too. The only way is to clone the table and remove those elements.